# java script regex - match the overflow of a string

Tags: javascript, regex, textarea, overflow

I am searching for a regex which matches exactly the opposite of that `/^.{0,140}/`.
I want to mark the overflow in a textarea so the regex has to match everything over a given length (140 signs) until the end.

I hope, you could help me.

Thanks, Tim

Answer (score 1):

Why use regex when you have [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)?

```
var everythingOver140 = text.substr(140);
```

From MDN:

> str.substr(start[, length])
>
> The substr() method returns the characters in a string beginning at the specified location through the specified number of characters.
>
> ...
>
> If length is omitted, substr() extracts characters to the end of the string.

Comment: Thanks! That was, what i searched for! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var overflow = string.match(/^.{0,140}(.*)$/).pop();
```